# Regularity of map

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be an immersion of regularity $C^{k, \alpha}$ for $k \geq 2$. Suppose that $U$ is a neighborhood of $M$ and $\chi$ is a vector field in $U$ of regularity $C^{k-1}$. Assume that $M$ flows along the vector field $\chi$, i.e. we get a map $F: M \times [0, \epsilon] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Can you tell me what tpe of regularity $F$ is?